# How to concatenate char array elements and cast/convert them to float?

Tags: c++, casting, concatenation, winsock

I am using Winsock, I want to send some values from Simulink to my own program and then I'll use that values in my mathematical equations. My computer is 64-bits, so that a char is 2 bytes and a float is 8 bytes. I want to get 3 elements in my buffer so that I declared my buffer as char buffer[12]. Now I need to merge buffer[0],buffer[1],buffer[2],buffer[3] and buffer[4],buffer[5],buffer[6],buffer[7] and ... so on and want to have a value like 12.23456. How can I do this and cast (or convert) it to float in order to use that values in my mathematical equations?

Here what I tried so far:

```
#pragma once 
#pragma comment(lib, "Ws2_32.lib")
#include <Windows.h>
#include <WinSock.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <iostream>


using namespace std;
int main(){

    WSAData wsaData;
    WORD DllVersion = MAKEWORD(2,2);
    int startup_RetVal = WSAStartup(DllVersion,&wsaData);

    SOCKET sSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP);

    SOCKADDR_IN addr;

    addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    addr.sin_port = htons(2222);

    bind(sSocket, (SOCKADDR*)&addr, sizeof(addr));
    char buf[12];

    recvfrom(sSocket,buf,sizeof(buf),NULL,NULL,NULL);

    char myString[4];
    strcpy(myString,buf[0]);
    strcat(myString,buf[1]);
    strcat(myString,buf[2]);
    strcat(myString,buf[3]);

    //cast it to float

    return 0;
```

}

This code does not compile because it has errors about strings.

Comment: A language tag would be appropriate. You can be sure yours isn't the only one in the world, and not the only one which winsock can be utilised from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is some confusion in your question. A `char` occupies 1 byte, 64-bit system or not,
and a `float` occupies 4 bytes. However, you should express the size of a float simply as `sizeof(float)`
to avoid an unnecessary assumption.

Your Windows PC is a little-endian system and I assume that Simulink is transmitting the values to your program as 32-bit little-endian floats, so there is no endian-conversion to worry about. (But
check the Simulink settings in case I am wrong either about the 32-bit or the little-endian).

I also assume the values are being transimitted such that you can count on receiving 3 at time,
as you want to (though I don't know why you require them bundled in 3s).

In that case, your receive buffer, now declared as `char buf[12];` should be declared
as `char buf[sizeof(float) * 3];`

Then, delete:

```
char myString[4];
strcpy(myString,buf[0]);
strcat(myString,buf[1]);
strcat(myString,buf[2]);
strcat(myString,buf[3]);

//cast it to float
```

and replace it with:

```
float af[3];
for (unsigned i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
    memcpy(af + i,buf + (i * sizeof(float)),sizeof(float));
}
```

This will copy 3 consecutive floats from `buf` into the 3 floats `af[0]`, `af[1]`, `af[2]`. Read about `memcpy` [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/memcpy).

That is the sufficient to solve your problem. But I would strongly suggest that you check the
return value of `recvfrom` and act accordingly. If the call has been successful it will
return the number of bytes received as `int`; otherwise `SOCKET_ERROR`.

You need the return value to be `3 * sizeof(float)` for this code to work. More flexible code
would just ensure that it is a multiple of `sizeof(float)` and then extract as many floats as you have got. And in any case you need to handle `SOCKET_ERROR`.

As to the string-related compilation errors you were seeing, they were due to the same mistake
in your call `strcpy(myString,buf[0])` and in each your calls `strcat(myString,buf[n])`. The
signature of `strcpy` is:

```
char * strcpy ( char * destination, const char * source );
```

and that of `strcat` is:

```
char * strcat ( char * destination, const char * source );
```

In each case the second argument must be a `const char *` and in each case you are
passing a `char`. That is what the compiler's error messages were telling you:

```
error C2664: 'strcpy' : cannot convert parameter 2 from 'char' to 'const char *'
error C2664: 'strcat' : cannot convert parameter 2 from 'char' to 'const char *'
```

Answer (score 0):

Using C++11, you can do it painlessly in this way:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char buf[13] = "1.2378.40.00";

    for(int n=0; n<3; ++n){
        string s {buf[n*4],buf[n*4+1],buf[n*4+2],buf[n*4+3]};
        double value = stof(s);
        cout << value << endl;
    }
}
```

stof() is new since C++11. As is the initialization of s via an initializer list.